# Different Arrays in tableview

Tags: uitableview, tableview

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Abelia"]) {
        if ([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[SpeciesViewController class]]) {
            SpeciesViewController *Species = (SpeciesViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
            Species.SpeciesInt = 0;
            }
        } 
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    if (SpeciesInt == 0)
        return [abeliaArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SpeciesNameCell";

    SpeciesNameCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[SpeciesNameCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SpeciesNameCell"];

        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }

    if (SpeciesInt == 0)
        cell.SpeciesNameLabel.text = [abeliaArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Im not sure where the problem in this 3 methods, it runs but the abeliaArray will run in place of the other arrays when I try to push. I have other arrays but when I push those the objects in the abeliaArray will show instead of the objects for that array.

Comment: add sample content of abeliaArray

Comment: abeliaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                  initWithObjects:@"Abelia grandiflora 'Rika1'", @"Abelia chinensis", @"Abelia x 'Edward Goucher'",@"Abelia x 'Mardi Gras'", @"Abelia x Rose Creek", @"Abelia x grandiflora", @"Abelia x grandiflora 'Kaleidoscope'", @"Abelia x grandiflora 'Little Richard'", @"Abelia x grandiflora 'Prostrata'", @"Abelia x grandiflora 'Sunrise'", nil];
   
    abeliophyllumArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]
                          initWithObjects:@"Abeliophyllum distichum", @"Abeliophyllum distichum 'Roseum'", nil];

Comment: There is 2 arrays in there when I push the abeliophyllum array the abelia array content will appear